# How to validate Integer or long in spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

```
class employee{
...
private long phone;
...
}
```

I want to validate phone number using spring jsr303 validator, In my Controller I am using @valid. I am successfully validating entered value is number or string by using generic typeMismatch placing in error message property file.

But I want to validate entered number format is correct or not.(@pattern for string only)

How to achieve this one,please suggest me.

Comment: Phone numbers are not numbers as they also consist of symbols like +, *, #, pause... You can't store them in integer variables. And how do you determine the number of 0s in the prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally phone numbers are String and you can validate by using @Pattern, but if you want to validate any fields you can do like this.

Custom annotation Javax validator

```
@javax.validation.Constraint(validatedBy = { PhoneNumberConstraintValidator.class })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidPhoneNumber {
}

public class PhoneNumberConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPhoneNumber, Long> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(final ValidPhoneNumber constraintAnnotation) {
        // nop
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Long value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       //your custom validation logic 
    }
}

class employee{
...
private long phone;

@ValidPhoneNumber
public Long getPhone() { return phone; } 
...
}
```

OR simpler if you have hibernate validator, you can just add this method in your entity class.

```
@org.hibernate.validator.AssertTrue
public boolean validatePhoneNumber() { }
```